# Why do I need to use reflection to instantiate a generic, given a type object?

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a list of Type objects corresponding to my entities, and I want to use those Types to instantiate corresponding generic binders...well let me just show this:

```
foreach (Type entitytype in Core.EntityList.Entities)
        {   
Type generictype = typeof(CustomBinders.Binder<>);
Type actualtype = generictype.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { entitytype });
IModelBinder custombinder = (IModelBinder)Activator.CreateInstance(actualtype);
.....................
```

The above works: each binder created is then later added to a dictionary of binders to be used by the mvc app. But why am I forced to use reflection? I believe this involves runtime vs compile time, which I don't understand. The types list is there at compile time.

If anyone can suggest a different pattern and/or explain these things to me then that would be nice. It seems like given a type object, I should be able to instantiate an object just using new. What is dynamic about what I am trying to do?

Comment: The question boils down to this: why can't I do Type T = typeof(int); list<T> = new list<T>(); or something similar. I will continue to try and improve my understanding of this. I am also looking into design-time T4 templates to address the case in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use `new`, you might think of doing something like this:

```
foreach (Type entityType in Core.EntityList.Entities)
{   
    IModelBinder obj = new CustomBinders.Binder<entityType>()
    // Then add it to the dictionary
}
```

However, this is illegal in C# - it will give you the error "Type or namespace name expected". Generics need a type parameter defined at compile-time so that it can provide all its compile-time checks. Thus, you need to use reflection to do this dynamically.

As for what reflection is actually doing in this case:

```
Type generictype = typeof(CustomBinders.Binder<>);
```

This gets a reference to the "*unbound*" generic type (i.e. it hasn't been given its type parameter yet).

```
Type actualtype = generictype.MakeGenericType(new Type[] { entitytype });
```

This gives you a reference to the "*constructed*" type - that is, the one with entitytype as the type parameter (i.e. `CustomBinders.Binder<entityType>`)

```
IModelBinder custombinder = (IModelBinder)Activator.CreateInstance(actualtype);
```

This constructs the object for you.

Comment: thx but since the List<Type> is there at compile time, I don't get why it's illegal. Seems like it's there just as well as if I had typed it in manually.

Comment: But the Type part is not defined at compile time. In my (illegal) example, the variable entityType only gets its value at runtime.

Comment: For instance, can you tell me; just by looking at my example; what value entityType will have at runtime?

Comment: hmm, it could just "new" one for each entry in the List<Type>.......sort of like if I typed the T in somewhere else instead of directly.

Comment: But again, you're talking about what it's doing at *runtime*. The C# compiler does not allow you to do what you are suggesting. If you want to use new, then you will need to actually write out `Binder<string>`, `Binder<int>` `Binder<whatever>`. If you want to do it dynamically, you **must** do it using reflection. C# does not provide a way to do this. If they did, type-safety would be a pain!

Comment: I don't see what would be wrong with: Type T = typeof(int); list<T> = new list<T>();

Comment: @the_law you aren't guaranteed that T will be the integer type at runtime.  In your example, sure, but in reality, the Type object could represent any type, and thus the compiler doesn't know what type to bind, since that instance doesn't exist at compile time.

Comment: Lets say, for example, that you get your type objects from a configuration file (a common scenario, look at ASP.NET MembershipProviders).  You don't know what those types will be until they are read in and the type objects created, which happens at runtime.  The compiler can't see the future, and thus doesn't know what type to bind.

Comment: If it is because typeof(int) is not evaluated until runtime then I do get it.

Comment: @the_law: that is more or less the case, yes. I'm not 100% sure about when typeof(int) is evaluated (compile- or run-time); but certainly, if C# permitted your example a few comments above, then they would also have to allow certain other things.

Comment: For instance, imagine that you had a textbox where the user could enter a type as a string. They could write "System.Int32" or "System.String" or "MyAssembly.Banana". If you were to then retrieve the Type object using `Type.GetType`, you could have absolutely any type that exists. Let's call that Type 'T'. If you were to then type `List<T>`, do you see that it could be a list of absolutely any type? This is why C# disallows this - even if, in your example, it might be possible to predict what types will exist at runtime, in the example I just gave, it is impossible to predict.

Comment: Smashery, yes in your last example the type is clearly not known until runtime, like in examples where data is pulled out from a file at runtime. In my own example of course a list of types was provided at compile time for the compiler to use, and it seems as though the compiler could have just thrown us a bone by using the list, but didn't.

Comment: True - but we can't expect the compiler to know everything. As far as the compiler is concerned, another thread might have changed your list before it is used. The compiler probably does do some code analysis, but not to the extent you are hoping for. There are so many reasons why the compiler might get it wrong, that the C# language designers decided that generics would not do what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to build a table. You already know the dimensions up front, what material to use, how much it'll cost and so on, so you just go ahead and create a table.

`var table = new Table();`

Let's say you now want to expand that and build other people's tables for them as well, so you put a box out where people can put the plans for their custom tables. The box is there from the start, but you have no idea which plans are going to come through that box, and there could be an arbitrary number of them, so you'll have to work it on on the fly.

`foreach(Type plan in planBox)
Activator.CreateInstance(plan);`

The difference is that a Type is a piece of metadata that you have at runtime about a given object (the plans, so to speak). If you knew the type at compile time, you'd put it into your code directly, but you have no idea what's going to come through your `Core.EntityList.Entities` box and so you have to use reflection to use that runtime information appropriately.

The point is, if you are using runtime information then you must use runtime capabilities. If all of the types are known at compile time, do not use Type objects.

Comment: I think I get it: typeof(int) isn't evaluted until runtime, hence I can't do: Type T = typeof(int); list<T> = new list<T>(); Since T isn't known until runtime, and type safety requires it at compile time.

Comment: typeof(int) is a compile-time construct that produces metadata that is usable at runtime. To use generics in the form of List<T>, T must be a type known and specified at compile-time. For example, you could say List<int> but you could not say List<someVariableDeterminedAtRuntime>.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. All my types are known and specified at compile time, that's why I was wondering why reflection is needed.